# google.golang.org/appengine/datastore vs cloud.google.com/go/datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I built a small go app, for use in AppEngine. I run the go locally through `go run ..`, and I am trying to use the datastore.

I run the datastore emulator locally through `gcloud beta emulators datastore start` and by exporting `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` the go app can locally connect to it.

So I built my app using `cloud.google.com/go/datastore`, but when I deployed this to AppEngine any go code that connects to the datastore seems to make the whole app fail with a timeout.

Whilst trying to debug this I ran into code using `google.golang.org/appengine/datastore` and writing some test code I got things to work on AppEngine.

However this *datastore* does not seem to be able to connect to the datastore emulator.

1. Has anyone run into the timeout issue when using `cloud.google.com/go/datastore`? I seem to read on different answers that people say to use *this* package and not the golang.org package for some reason.
2. Can I use `cloud.google.com/go/datastore` on AppEngine? I would prefer to use this package, since it works with the datastore emulator.

I am using the following code, in short:

```
import "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
...
ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
...
client, err := datastore.NewClient(dsCtx, projectID)
...
key := datastore.IDKey(TestKind, testID, nil)
err = client.Get(ctx, key, &data)
```

This is the code that times out on AppEngine, but works fine locally.

The code that likewise works on AppEngine is this:

```
import "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
...
ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
key := datastore.NewKey(ctx, TestKind, "", testID, nil)
err := datastore.Get(ctx, key, &data)
```

And this will fail locally with the following:

```
Metadata fetch failed: Get http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/gae_project: dial tcp: lookup metadata: no such host
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [**Connecting to Cloud Datastore with App Engine** section in the App Engine Cloud Datastore Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/#connecting_to_datastore_name_short_with_app_engine):

> You cannot use the Cloud Datastore client library with Go applications
>   in the App Engine standard environment.

Basically, `cloud.google.com/go/datastore` is for using Cloud Datastore *outside of the App Engine standard environment*. This includes non-App Engine environments, as well as the App Engine flexible environment.

`google.golang.org/appengine/datastore` is for using it *within the App Engine standard environment*.

For local testing of the App Engine standard environment, look into using [dev_appserver.py](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/local-devserver-command) which provides integration with the Cloud Datastore emulator via the `--support_datastore_emulator` flag.

Comment: Ok thanks that clears things up, better than "You cannot use the Cloud Datastore client library with Go applications in the App Engine standard environment."

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to accept it.